# C#: Class to use with Object

Tags: c#, class, dll, object

How can I create a class (in a DLL) that is used with a specific object? Like for instance, a class that Bitmaps call on to do certain things. e.g.

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap;
bmp.ThingToDo():

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

You can add your method to the class Bitmap like the following:

```
public static class CustomExtension
{
     public static void ThingToDo(this Bitmap bitmap)
     {
         // add your functionality here and use bitmap
     }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I only recently started using Extension Methods, and now I can't get enough of them. Example: I have an extension method that takes a past date and returns an "age".  My birthdate for example `12/07/1980` returns `29`. Love extension methods.

Comment: you can use return type to bool to check if the task you're doing is done or not...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of an Extension Method including the Class and Namespace

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class BitmapExtensions
    {
        [Extension()]
        public static void MakeMyImageCool(Bitmap img)
        {
            //'# do something with your image here.
        }
    }
}
```

And then to call it

```
Bitmap img = MySourceImage;
img.MakeMyImageCool();
```

Notice how even though there is a parameter request in the method, you are not passing a parameter in the call.  That's because the extension method already uses the "img" as the parameter.

Comment: I'd still +1 Homam, I just wanted to clarify a bit.